# Performance Degradation due to too many variables?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript

I'm working on refactoring our current email code for clarity and ease of editing.  I'm curious if there's a noticeable performance degradation in the send time, or any other aspect of the email, if I add more defined variables.  Currently we often redefine the same variables multiple times in the same email in different sections, and I'm looking to create new variables instead of redefining the same variables for different sections.

I'm guessing that the difference in adding a few variables is negligible, but I'm more curious about the email execution in a large scale concept.  Has anyone noticed a lag or any difficulties when they have a large number of variables defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen some crazy-huge and complex scripted emails that send to millions of subscribers.

The only thing the SFMC folks caution against is using SSJS in your emails, since it requires the OMM to spawn some new processes to translate it.

I wouldn't worry about creating a bunch of extra variables, to be honest.